# Как настроить автоподдомены?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать автоподдомены? 
Задача следующая: пишу сайт "Справочник организации", на нем будет ПРОМО режим. А для этого режима нужно сделать возможность автоматически создавать поддомены типа: firma.mysite.ru.

Т.е. когда я через админ панель буду ставить галочку "Сделать фирму промо организацией", и вводить название домена, он должен автоматически включиться. Сложность возникла в том, что сам скрипт должен как то запускаться из одной директории. Так как нет смысла в каждый поддомен копировать одно и то же. Так как промо фирмы будут однотипными, за исключением CSS.

Может быть это можно организовать посредством .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним .htaccess тут не обойтись, нужны настройки виртуального хоста, в nginx просто добавить в server_name mysite.ru *.mysite.ru, apache не юзаю. теперь поддомены и сам домен направленны в один скрипт, а он уже распределяет кого куда отправить.

---

исключения в .htaccess  примерно так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.mysite\.ru 
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

---

Не забудьте добавить DNS запись  CNAME в name "*" а в hostname "@"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Примерно так и представлял себе, но тут есть маленький ньюанс, на сайте есть несколько поддоменов, которые перенаправлять не нужно. Как тогда прописать эти исключения в .htaccess.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!!!